# RecyclerView not showing - Xamarin .Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

To me, it seems there's nothing wrong in my code but my recyclerView is not showing up. Please look into my code if the adapter is well set up. Thank you.  Please what am i missing in my adapter? The page appears empty although i see that the datasnapShot in my adapter runs but my recyclerView doesn't show.

**Adapter**

```
 public class PhotoHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {


           public ImageView ImgPhotos;

            public PhotoHolder(View itemView):base(itemView)
            {
                ImgPhotos = (ImageView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageView);

            }

            public class PhotoAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, IValueEventListener
            {

                public PhotoAdapter(List<Photos> Photos, Context mContext)
                {
                    this.Photos = Photos;
                    this.mContext = mContext;
                    photos = (PhotosActivity)mContext;

                    mDatabaseImage = FirebaseDatabase.Instance.Reference.Child("Photos");

                    mDatabaseImage.AddValueEventListener(this);
                }



                public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
                {
                    hold = holder as PhotoHolder;
                    hold.ImgPhotos.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.cheese_5);
                }



                public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
                {
                    View v = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_photos, parent, false);
                    PhotoHolder holder = new PhotoHolder(v);

                    return holder;
                }


                public override int ItemCount
                {

                    get { return Photos.Count; }

                }

                public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }

               public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
                {
                    var items = snapshot.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();


                    foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
                    {

                        map = (HashMap)item.Value;
                        imageUrl = new FilePhotos(map.Get("URL").ToString());
                    }

                }


            }

        }
```

**PhotoActivity**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.content_frame);
            LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PhotoView, content);

            adapter = new PhotoAdapter(Photos, this);

            rv = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
            rv.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            rv.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rv.SetAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: Your code looks ok, check your layout file and see your recyclerview height and width. also try removing the animator and check for changes

Comment: I saw your newest case asking about searching in the recyclerview, so have you solved this issue?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, yes i have solved it but my search is not working like expected